# Images loading without full resolution (Julia)

Tags: image, julia, resolution

I have a .NEF file on my Desktop titled "my_image.nef". If I look at the details of the image, I see a resolution of 4256x2832:

[image]

When I try to open this with Julia, I get a two-dimensional array of size 120x160.

[image]

How do I get a full-resolution array to load? Why is it loading a much smaller version of the original image?

Comment: It's basically impossible to trouble shoot this without an example image file.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski I found a sample file at https://filesamples.com/formats/nef , and the results are similar. A `4288 x 2844` image is read in as a `320 x 212` array, and shown with only that many pixels by `ImageView.imshow`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on various RAW file formats, but it's probably loading the [thumbnail preview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format). There's good reason to hope this may be fairly easily resolvable: like many RAW formats, it appears to be a [variation on TIFF](http://lclevy.free.fr/nef/), and Julia's [TiffImages](https://github.com/tlnagy/TiffImages.jl) package is an amazingly good TIFF library. It's possible you'd have to create a "wrapper package" specifically for RAW or NEF, but it's might end up being a fairly short exercise in piecing together the correct series of calls to `TiffImages` internals. I encourage you to file an issue at TiffImages to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Julia command prompt to iteratively call ImageMagick, locally converting all the .NEF files to .PNG files and reading in the PNG files as arrays.

```
using Glob
using Shell

filenames = glob(string("*",".NEF"), <IMAGE DIR>)
for file in filenames
    fname = split(split(file,"\\")[end],".")[1]
    fname1 = string(img_folder, fname, ".NEF")
    fname2 = string(img_folder, fname, ".png")
    cmd = string("convert ", fname1, " ", fname2)
    Shell.run(cmd)
end
```

Sloppy, but there didn't seem to be a tidy Julia-based package that worked well.